# Free Goerli testETH? Why is there a Goerli faucet shortage

Tags: testnets, goerli, faucets, sepolia

Anyone else struggling to get Goerli Ethereum? Feel free to use Alchemy's free goerli faucet - [goerlifaucet.com](https://goerlifaucet.com).

You can use this faucet to get more testETH every day.  We created it because we strongly think it's against web3 ethos to charge for testETH. In return, we just ask you make this a good experience for everyone and not spam.

---

Alternative, if anyone is testing on Sepolia (Ethereum's other testnet), Alchemy also has a free Sepolia faucet - [sepoliafaucet.com](https://sepoliafaucet.com)

Comment: Why i got error 504 when try goerlifaucet now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. I've been using Alchemy's Goerli faucet. If you log in to [Alchemy Dashboard](https://dashboard.alchemy.com/) and create and use a free App, it will upgrade your faucet to 0.5ETH vs 0.2ETH, which is very helpful.